# Performance of loading Time and influxdb

Tags: performance, load, grafana, influxdb

I have a question in context of performance of loading Time and influxdb.

I have a Grafana Dashboard, but the loading time is very very slow because in the influxdb are a huge mass of data sysstat (pidstat, mpstat, vmstat ...).

I've already deleted useless tag rows, add filter but still the dashboard needs a very long time to load.

How can I deal with it?